# C++ Program exited with code 01 no code was executed

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, arm

When I run my program on my computer everything works as expected. But recently I've moved the app to a wandboard dual which is running Ubuntu 12.04 (same as my computer). The program has a structure similar to:

```
...
headers
...

bool continueStuff = true;

log4cplus::Logger makeLogger(std::string str)
{
    ...
    Init custom loggers
    make loggers
    set properties
    return logger
}

log4cplus::Logger logger = makeLogger("MainLogger");
void signalHandler(int signum)
{
    switch(signum)
    {   
        // Fatal signals
        case 1:
        case 2:
        case 3:
        case 4:
        case 6:
        case 8:
        case 9:
        case 10: 
        case 11: 
        case 12: 
        case 13: 
        case 14: 
        case 15: 
            printf("Fatal signal(%d) received. Shutting down\n", signum);
            LOG4CPLUS_FATAL(logger, "Fatal signal(" << signum << ") received. Shutting down.");

            exit(signum);
            break;

        // Non-fatal signals
        default:
            LOG4CPLUS_INFO(logger, "Non-fatal signal(" << signum << ") received.");
    }   
}

...
functions
...

int main()
{
    printf("Starting\n");
    signal(SIGINT, signalHandler);
    ...
}
```

The program compiles perfectly fine on the wandboard but when I run it it exits immediately. I've tried running it through gdb setting breakpoints at the main method, the global variable declarations and any contructors that are called before main. I also have print statements throughout all code that is executed before main yet nothing is printed.

The g++ versions are the same on my machine and the wandboard.
Libraries are all the same version (with the exception of one) but I don't believe this is the issue due to the fact that I am not seeing any compiler errors.

I also never return a positive exit status, my app either returns 0 for success or -1 for failure. As you can see in the code above I also handle all signals received by the program and print and error message before exiting.

**UPDATE:**

valgrind outputs:

```
==18828== Command: ./app
==18828== Parent PID: 18092
==18828==
==18828== Jump to the invalid address stated on the next line
==18828==    at 0x388: ???
==18828==  Address 0x388 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==18828==
==18828==
==18828== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==18828==  Bad permissions for mapped region at address 0x388
==18828==    at 0x388: ???
==18828==
```

**UPDATE 2:**

I was using a pre-compiled library, after reading the output from:
    readelf -AW libPrecompileLib.so
I found out that it was compiled for the cortex-a9 processor where as all of the system libraries were compiled for 7-A processor. Since the library couldn't talk to the system it wouldn't run.

Is it possible for me to compile my app for the cortex-a9 processor?

I have tried:

```
g++ -mcpu=cortex-a9 -c src.cpp -o app
```

but since the since nothing is linked (as per the -c) it's not executable. Once I remove the -c however, the readelf output says that it's 7-A.

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, you are calling `exit(signum)` which will forcefully kill the program, and not execute code that follows.

Comment: @Cyber that's his signal handler which is not executed unless a signal is raised.

Comment: @Rick but you _do_ exit with positive exit codes in case of signals.

Comment: I only `exit(signum)` when it is a fatal signal so there would be no code executed anyway. And it's unlikely that this code is even being run because the print statement isn't being displayed on the console.

Comment: @PeterSchneider you are correct, I miss spoke when I said that I don't. But either way I'm extremely doubtful that this is the issue due to the fact that there is not printing of "Fatal signal(%d) received...". There's also the fact that the assignment of the signalHandler is set after the first print statement in main.

Comment: As to the possible reasons, I cannot see any from what you provided. Apparently it's something which happens before main(), e.g. a runtime environment prob or invalid code for your CPU or global/static initializers. I'd now try the obvious: Make sure that a trivial program runs at all; then add features from your app until it starts crashing again, resp. use a binary division strategy for finding the problematic part of your code. Mock the parts you comment out for the test.

Comment: I think Peter might have it right.  A great way to make code non-portable is to initialize variables at global scope. I can't really tell from your program structure what your looking for but your initialization may be out of order.

Comment: After taking Peter's suggestion and slowly building up the app I realized that the issue was that library that wasn't the same version. It seems like it isn't meant to work on my wandboard. On a side note, @jnbbender, what is it about global variables that makes a program non-portable. I'm fully aware as to why it's bad practice and I tried to avoid it, eventually I might get around to turning my main file into an OO design but until then globals are required.

Comment: My apologies, I did not mean non-portable.  I meant you could not guarantee initialization order.

Answer (score 0):

http://linux.die.net/man/2/signal
Note the section urging you to use `sigaction` since `signal` isn't very portable.

Comment: Although that is true and might cause an issue at a later date, I am running Ubuntu 12.04 on both my machine and the wandboard as well as using the same version g++ to compile the app. As such there should be no portability issues between them.